# xml mischief when using structs containing slices?

Tags: xml, go

I tried the following code in an effort to understand why I'm having issues with my xml in golang.

As I understand it, I should be able to marshal a struct and then unmarshal the resulting data back into a struct of the same type?

Result I expected is a parent struct containing a slice of childs, instead that children slice is nil?

[playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/wM1-eH7x9C)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Parent struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"parent"`
    Children []Child  `xml:"children"`
}

type Child struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"child"`
    ID      int      `xml:"ID"`
}

func main() {
    children := make([]Child, 3)

    for i := range children {
        children[i] = Child{ID: i}
    }

    p1 := Parent{Children: children}

    data, err := xml.Marshal(p1)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error during marshal: %v\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Raw XML: %v\n", string(data))

    p2 := Parent{}

    err = xml.Unmarshal(data, &p2)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error during unmarshal: %v\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Unmarshalled struct: %v\n", p2)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work quite like this: There is no ad hoc bijection between a struct and a XML.

E.g. you generate the following XML

```
<parent><child><ID>0</ID></child><child><ID>1</ID></child></parent>
```

because your `Child` type has a field `XMLName xml.Name` with a xml tag "child".
That's how Marshaling works. From http://tip.golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal

> The name for the XML elements is taken from, in order of preference:
>
> - the tag on the XMLName field, if the data is a struct
> - the value of the XMLName field of type xml.Name
> - the tag of the struct field used to obtain the data
> - the name of the struct field used to obtain the data
> - the name of the marshalled type

Now take a look what happens if you try to Unmarshal it:
Your `Parent` type tags its field `Children []Child` with "children"
but your XML simply has no `<children>` tag inside, only `<child>`.

If you use

```
type Parent struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"parent"`
    Children []Child  `xml:"child"`  // "child", not "children"
}
```

it works like you intended.